# Superposed the sprites with libGDX

Tags: java, resize, libgdx, sprite

I would like to superpose two sprites but, when I resize my windows the sprites moves ...

**My code:**

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ( height < width ){
        spriteAbalone.setScale(height/700f);
        billeBlanche.setScale(height/700f);
    }
    else{
        spriteAbalone.setScale(width/700f);
        billeBlanche.setScale(width/700f);
    }
    spriteAbalone.setPosition((width-700)/2, (height - 700)/2);
    billeBlanche.setPosition((width-400)/2,(height-400)/2);
    camera.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
    camera.update();
}


@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float screenW = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float screenH = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, screenW, screenH);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();  
    spriteAbalone = new Sprite(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/AbaloneCS5.gif")), 0, 0, 704, 704));
    spriteAbalone.setSize(700 , 700);
    spriteAbalone.setOrigin(704/2,704/2);
    billeBlanche = new Sprite(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/billeblanche.gif")),0,0,200,200));
    billeBlanche.setSize(65, 65);
    billeBlanche.setOrigin(704/2,704/2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Sprite#setOrigin](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setOrigin%28float,%20float%29) Sets the origin in relation to the sprite's position for scaling and rotation. In this code you set the same origin for both sprites despite one of them being considerably smaller:

```
spriteAbalone = new Sprite(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/AbaloneCS5.gif")), 0, 0, 704, 704));
spriteAbalone.setSize(700 , 700);
spriteAbalone.setOrigin(704/2,704/2);
billeBlanche = new Sprite(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/billeblanche.gif")),0,0,200,200));
billeBlanche.setSize(65, 65);
billeBlanche.setOrigin(704/2,704/2);
```

Change the billeBlanche origin to this:

```
billeBlanche.setOrigin(200/2,200/2);
```

Also,in **resize** the position you set for the sprites is fixed -always (width-700)/2 or (width-400)/2- but your sprite sizes is different. Thats the reason they **"move"**.